# Send variable to the same function

Tags: javascript, html

I want a function that looks for elements with the "comment" class, and if the number of comments has changed, (if there is a new comment) it will call an other function. So this is what I did:

```
function main(num0){
    var comments = document.getElementsByClassName("comment");
    var num = comments.length;
    if (num!=num0){
        //function to call();
        console.log("New Comment");
    }
    setTimeout(main(num),10); //check every 10 for new comments
}
main(0);
```

num0 is the number of comments the last time the function was called so I try to recall the same function but num0 takes the value of num, but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `setInterval`. **calling recursion at higher rate may cause different errors after some time**.

```js
let num = 0;
setInterval(()=>{
    var comments = document.getElementsByClassName("comment");
    var num1 = comments.length;
    if (num!=num1){
        //function to call();
        console.log("New Comment");
        num=num1
    }
},10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `setTimeout` is invalid; you are calling the function `main` instead of providing `setTimeout` with a callback. I also believe you need to pass `num0` instead of `num` in your timeout.

Try this:

```js
function main(num0){
    var comments = document.getElementsByClassName("comment");
    var num = comments.length;
    if (num!=num0){
        //function to call();
        console.log("New Comment");
    }
    setTimeout(main, 10, num0); // Changed this line
}
main(0);
```

Review this regarding the setTimeout function:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: changed  setTimeout(main, 10, num0); for  setTimeout(main, 10, num); and worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout takes a function reference. In your case you aren't passing the reference, you are passing the result of that function by calling it.

Example of syntax that does what you intend it to do:

```
setTimeout(() => main(num),10); //check every 10 for new comments
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp